# Header file for u_short?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, header

Can anybody tell me the header file to be used for `u_short` and `u_char` etc :

I have seen it being used in `sys/socket.h`:

```
typedef u_char      sa_family_t;
```

But when i used that header in my program, it gives me error:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\sys\socket.h(52):
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'sa_family_t'
```

I think the solution is inclusion of header, but i dont know what header is it !

Comment: Not really a windows coder, but the socket header on windows is usually Winsock2.h

Comment: Thats correct, i could figure that out.

Now, when i compile my program, it compiles successfully but gives me the following error when i run it :

Module2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Documents and Settings\jhap1\Desktop\NW_Diagnose\Module2\New Folder\Module2\Debug\Module2.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Module2.exe': Loaded 'C:\WINNT\system32\ntdll.dll',Cannot find or open the pdb file

Comment: If i run it as admin, it works.

Answer (score 0):

> Header file for u_short?

We just ramped up testing on less-frequently-used platforms. We ran into a similar issue under Cygwin i686 with GCC 5.3 and `-std=c++11`. The code has been stable for about 15 years (give or take).

I can't find a standard header for it.

Grepping on OS X and Linux shows `u_short` is fairly prevalent, even though there are 0 hits under Cygwin now (JUN 2016):

```
# Ununtu
$ grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include | wc -l
 31

# OS X
$ grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include | wc -l
 122

# Solaris
$ /usr/gnu/bin/grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include/ | wc -l
 125
```

And:

```
# Ubuntu
$ grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include | grep typedef
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h:typedef unsigned short int __u_short;
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:typedef __u_short u_short;
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:typedef __u_short u_short;
/usr/include/linux/coda.h:typedef unsigned short u_short;

# OS X
$ grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include | grep typedef
/usr/include/netinet/ip_mroute.h:typedef u_short vifi_t;        /* type of a vif index */
/usr/include/netinet6/ip6_mroute.h:typedef u_short mifi_t;      /* type of a mif index */
/usr/include/sys/types.h:typedef    unsigned short      u_short;

# Solaris
$ /usr/gnu/bin/grep -IR "u_short" /usr/include/ 2>/dev/null | grep typedef
/usr/include/sys/types.h:typedef unsigned short u_short;
/usr/include/rpcsvc/nfs_acl.h:typedef u_short o_mode;
```

You should be safe with a cast to `unsigned short` or perhaps a `uint16_t` (on Unix and Linux from `<stdint.h>`) rather than `u_short`.